# How should we type a variable declaration which gets its value from a call to generic function f<T>() : T?

Tags: typescript

Consider the following TypeScript example:

```
type Book = {
    name: string;
}

const getSomething = <T>() : T => {
    // Magically returns something of type T
}

const book : Book = getSomething();
const anotherBook = getSomething<Book>();
```

I understand that with `book`, we declare a variable named `book` of type `Book` and we get its value by calling a generic `getSomething` function without explicitly providing the function call with a `Book` type. However, since `book` is of type `Book`, TS will infer that the generic function `getSomething` will be retuning a `Book` type value as well.

With `anotherBook`, we declare a variable named `anotherBook` without an explicit type and we get its value by calling a generic `getSomething` function while providing it with a `Book` type. Since we provide the `Book` type when we call `getSomething`, TS will infer that the generic function `getSomething` will be returning a `Book` type value and therefore `anotherBook` is of type `Book` as well.

There is technically a third way to do this, which is:

```
const thirdBook : Book = getSomething<Book>();
```

So as far as I understand, this just seems a matter of how much we want to explicitly tell TS and if we would like TS to infer the type of the variable, the type for the function call or neither of them.

Am I missing anything here? Can each of the three approaches always be used? Is one of them considered a better practise over the other ones?

I guess if we consider something like the common `useState` approach in React:

```
const [fourthBook, setFourthBook] = useState<Book>(new Book(...));
```

And

```
const [fifthBook, setFifthBook] : [Book, React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<Book>>] = useState(new Book(...));
```

We can see that the former approach is more convenient than the latter, but is there any non-syntatic difference? I don't know.

On a side-note, there doesn't seem to be a sane way to tell TS to infer the type of `setFifthBook` automatically when we have declare `fifthBook` to be of `Book` type. Well, other than using `any`.

```
const [fifthBook, setFifthBook] : [Book, ...Rest<> or auto or something?] = useState(new Book(...));
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? I feel like I just read 3 problems in one. Could you clarify what the question is? I'm not sure why you have 3 examples where you use `useState` and have some long type for the type annotation when it can be inferred. See @captain-yossarian's answer about that.

Answer (score 1):

Using explicit generic which is not infered from argument is justified in two cases:

1. When you have server request
2. When you pass empty array, for instance to `useState`:

```js
const [state, handleState] = useState([])

state // never[]

const [state, handleState] = useState<number[]>([])
state // number[]
```

If you are using an argument, you can omit explicit generic parameter because TS is able to infer it. For instance:

```js
const [fourthBook, setFourthBook] = useState(new Book(...));
fourthBook // Book
```

Hence, if your function expects an argument you can write it like this:

```js
const getSomething = <T>(arg: T) => {
    // Magically returns something of type T
}
```

More about function arguments inference- you can find in my [article](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments)